# How notes get stored in apps like evernote, notes, memo etc?

Tags: android, save

I'm building an android app. I would like to implement the save button like that in evernote,notes, memo etc and I want to store the data like they do in that. How to generate different file names to store data? Please help me do that.

Comment: store that in your DB? are you having any problem with that?

Comment: But how can you explain briefly. DB is used to store datas in table right... Here the user might enter long texts

Comment: Actually it is asper your implementation. You can store it anywhere. You can also use SharedPreference if you need. This is something that can be done as per your interest.

Comment: Which is the best way to store?

Comment: I will go for storing it in a file. Because it is more secure

Comment: K... But here how to create different files with different names because the user might create many notes

Comment: No not like that. Use only one file. I am just suggesting you to save it in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

**SQLite**

Best way to store notes is `SQLite` , its more organized and secure and you wont need any different file names. Just use with one simple table .
here is Sample project [SQLite project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783073/A-Simple-Android-SQLite-Example).